# Apps Script Addon {docs, sheets, slides, forms} share a library that builds common menu that only shows default-option

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on

When the addon loads, the menu only display its Help-option.
Cloud Console logs: We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND.

The addons works. I noticed some minor differences while testing though actual files (one for each file-type) and testing Script-editor>Run>Test as addon... Yet I've managed to get them both working. **However** once installed (direct or domain), the add-on will only show one alternativ: Help.

I follow the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle) to the best of my ability and I've read up on the onInstall-issue but find myself at a loss.

Almost all code is shared in a common library: opAddonShared. Those file-agnostic functions are added to the end of the addon-menu: *opAddonShared.addSharedMenu(ui, menu)*

```
const langsClearEmptyCells = {en: " Clear Empty Cells", sv: " Ta bort tomma celler"};
const langsClearOtherSheets = {en: " Cut All Other Sheets", sv: " Skär bort andra blad"};

function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) { // ⚠ Addons are frustrating!
    return menu.addItem(' Install', "onInstall").addToUi();
  } 
  let isLimited = e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED
  let lang = isLimited ? Session.getActiveUserLocale() ? 'sv' : 'en' : opAddonShared.getLanguage()
  menu.addItem(langsClearEmptyCells[lang] || langsClearEmptyCells['en'],  'removeEmpty')
  menu.addItem(langsClearOtherSheets[lang] || langsClearOtherSheets['en'],  'deleteOtherSheets')
  
  if(!isLimited) {
    menu.addSeparator()
    menu = opAddonShared.addSharedMenu(ui, menu) //Appends file-agnostic functions
  }
  menu.addToUi()
}

function onInstall(e){
  opAddonShared.installSharedMenu()
  onOpen(e);
}

let callAddonLibraryFunction = (functionString, args) => {return opAddonShared[functionString](args)};
```

Comment: your currently deploying it as a sheets add-on, correct? I don't think it would work with anything else currently

Comment: The line of code: `let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` is specific to Sheets.  You can have generic code, but the main class or the document type would need to be a hard coded configuration setting for that document type. The new Workspace add-ons can display the same icon in multiple different types of documents, but as of the date of your post it's not available to Google Forms.

Comment: My example-snippet is from the Spreadsheet. When publishing an addon, you provide a meny for each file-fype. My addon works with all 4 types so I maintain 4 files which is why i use a library to create every file-agnostic function: menu = opAddonShared.addSharedMenu(ui, menu)

Comment: thumbs up for following the inversion of control principle when building the menu :) More on point - have you checked the logs, your function must be failing for some reason, is there anything unusual being logged? I would look particularly for the "you do not have permission" error types

Comment: @OlegValter Yes! I do have a less commonly occuring error aside from NOT_FOUND; Library with identifier opAddonShared is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?). I haven't given it mush thought as all five scripts share GCP-project and every file is shared within the domain. Have tried making library-file public without any noticable change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seem to have been versioning (file-menu matching GCP) and/or access-control for shared script (Drive-file or script-library).

After the "fix", the menu will contain the " Install"; for each file. After running onInstall(), the menu will be fully listed. It must be installed per-file; not per-user as I had wished/expected.

The sidebars are not yet working properly.